# operational error sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Пытаюсь обновить столбец БД следующей строкой кода:

```
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET resultintest =f'Число души пользователя:{first}\nЧисло судьбы пользователя:{second}\nЧисло при рассчете 2022 года:{third}' WHERE user_id==f'{message.from_user.id}'")
```

пишет следующее

> cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET resultintest =f'Число души
> пользователя:{first}\nЧисло судьбы пользователя:{second}\nЧисло при
> рассчете 2022 года:{third}' WHERE user_id==f'{message.from_user.id}'")
>
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'Число души пользователя:8 Число
> судьбы пользователя:11 Число при рассчете 2022 года:5'": syntax error

Answer (score 1):

У вас сразу несколько синтаксических ошибок:

- строковые литералы в SQL должны быть "обернуты" одинарными кавычками -

```
UPDATE users SET resultintest = 'f"..."' ...
-- NOTE: ---------------------> ^      ^
```

---

```
WHERE user_id==f'{message.from_user.id}'"
```

в SQL нет оператора `==` - используйте `=` для сравнения.

---

Но лучше, проще и безопаснее (`SQL Injections`) использовать **параметризированные** запросы - драйвер сам позаботиться об экранировании строк:

```
upd_val = f'Число души пользователя:{first}\nЧисло судьбы пользователя:{second}\nЧисло при рассчете 2022 года:{third}'
qry = f"""UPDATE users SET resultintest = ? WHERE user_id = ?"""
cursor.execute(qry, [upd_val, message.from_user.id])
```